# Accessing the fields of Database.query() results

Tags: apex, soql, controller, dynamic-soql

Database.query(query) returns sobjects.

I want to access each fields in this sobject to check the value on each field.

How is this done in controller?

Comment: Can you post the tried out code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Database.query` returns a `List<SObject>` you'll want to cast the result before you use it to access any fields. Once you've done that you can access the fields like you normally would.

```
List<Account> accounts = (List<Account>)Database.query(...);

// You can do the cast directly in the loop declaration, but I've not done so here for clarity
for(Account a : accounts)
{
    // Do something with your Accounts
}
```

You can access the fields without casting by using `get(String)` and `getSObject(Schema.SObjectField)`, but I wouldn't recommend using them unless you need the dynamic behaviour. By using the dynamic methods you lose all the type-safety features that Force.com provides.

Answer (score 2):

`Database.query(query)` returns a list of SOBJECT . So loop through the SObject using :

```
for(SObject s : LstSObjects ) {
//access each field values here using s.
//example as follows 
s.Name = 'ABC';

}
```

Use a list to manipulate or calculate values on Fields in SOBJECT .